# XMLHttpRequest.responseText is not rendering the json encoded output

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, smarty3

My `$request->generate( 'web_notifier' )` generated link:

```
header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );

# Die is used to ensure nothing else is being outputted further down the script

die( json_encode ( array(
    'session' => array(
        'token' => $request->session( 'crsf_token' )
    )
) ) );
```

When I visit this API link, I get this output (and I can see that the Content-Type in the header is set to application/json:

```
{"session":{"token":"3d096c30a00da9ab37019122622dac80edec6db0cf006d5f4450ecd8d813c692"}}
```

However, if I now try to use a `XMLHttpRequest` to view the `session.token`, like below, I get `Cannot read property 'token' of undefined` which tells me that it has not been rendered as JSON.

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = () => {
    console.log(req.responseText.session.token);
    console.log(req.responseText['session']['token']);
};
req.open( 'GET', '{{$request->generate( 'web_notifier' )}}' );
req.send();
```

I did a `console.log(req.responseText)` and can see that it is in String format - Why is this if I have specified the Content-Type correctly and used `json_encode()` ? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The json parsing is not automatic you need to passe your response into JSON.parse(str), also i advise you to use fetch instead of XMLHttpRequest it has a builin conversion.

```
fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(handler)
```

```js
jsonString = '{"data": "some_data"}'
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonString))
```

Comment: Was completely unaware of `fetch()` - I have modified my script to use the function. Is there a reason that I have to parse the string to json if I specify the content-type and json_encode it? I'll mark this as the correct answer when it lets me as this solved my issue

Comment: XMLHttpRequest is a legacy ajax function, fetch has better capabilities , the content type is meant to tell the Browser/Server so it know what type is expected so you can handle it on your own or via utilities (for example to prevent you from parsing non json format).